# Why I see Broken Images in All of My browsers

Tags: images, browser-cache

This happens sometimes and not often but I get certain images displayed as broken. Here's today's example which is relevant to Chrome, Firefox and IE:

[image]

Despite that I was being able to fix this by clearing cache through browser's options, I still wonder why this happens and why cache is not updated when I refresh page with F5 or refresh and renew page's cache with CTRL+F5?

Comment: how's your network connection in general? I've seen this where the connection is slow, you get the html of the page, but the browser times out before all the images load.

Comment: "why cache is not updated when I refresh page"  probably the most important words of the question. A refresh would usually restart all the downloading , not requiring one to fully clear the cache itself unless the parts and pieces were from a whole (like a flash site) and that never happens that way either.  A refresh should be enough to restart the whole process of loading the stuff into the netTemps and redrawing the page with them.

Comment: @cjb110 Connection is active and fast.